# Where I should place handler of emit?

Tags: vue.js

I have child `component` and want to pass some data to it's parent.
My child component looks like:

```
// <button @click="sendClick($event)">Send</button>
// ...
data: function (){
    return {
            mycode: ""
        }
    },
    methods: {
        sendClick(e)
        {
            bus.$emit('change', this.mycode);
        }
}
```

My parent component looks:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentView: 'past-form',
    mycode: ''
  },
  methods:
  {
    changeView()
    {
        this.currentView = 'past-form'
        console.log(this.mycode);
    },

  }, 

  created()
  {
        bus.$on('change', function(mycode){
            this.mycode = mycode;

        });
  }

})
```

1. I haven't found a better place for placing `bus.$on` (`bus` is declared globally) than in `created()`, but the docs state that `created()` is for stuff that should be initialized after the page is loaded. The `created()` block works; I checked it by placing in it `console.log(this.mycode)`, but should I move emit handler somewhere else?
2. It's look like my code does not execute `mycode: ''`, because `console.log(this.mycode);` does not print anything.

Comment: If your child is a direct child of the Vue, there is no need for a bus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, if your component is a direct child of your Vue, then there is no need for a bus.

That said, the `created` handler is fine for adding your `bus` event handler.

I expect the issue you have is a `this` issue. Try changing your handler to

```
bus.$on('change', mycode => this.mycode = mycode)
```

See [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484)

Here is an example.

```js
console.clear()

const bus = new Vue()

Vue.component("child", {
  template: `<button @click="sendClick($event)">Send</button>`,
  data: function() {
    return {
      mycode: "something"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sendClick(e) {
      bus.$emit('change', this.mycode);
    }
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentView: 'past-form',
    mycode: ''
  },
  methods: {
    changeView() {
      this.currentView = 'past-form'
      console.log(this.mycode);
    },

  },

  created() {
    bus.$on('change', mycode => {
        this.mycode = mycode
        this.changeView()
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child></child>
  Parent mycode: {{mycode}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how I can change call from child `changeView();` ?

Comment: @user1432751 I'm not sure I understand you. Do you want to call the `changeView` method in your event handler?

Comment: Yes, I need to call `changeView` after I am getting data. And show to user page "we got your data"

Comment: @user1432751 I updated the handler in the above code.